Updating foreign key ID does not update navigation property
This is my class:
public class tblProdLine : DBModel
{

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Supervisor")]
    public int? SupervisorID { get; set; }

    public virtual tblUser? Supervisor { get; set; }
}

In my window, Prodline.SupervisorID is bound to a combobox, so when the user chooses a new supervisor, its ID will be stored in SupervisorID:
<select @bind="plineModel.SupervisorID" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose a user...</option>
    @foreach (var user in UserViewModel.Items)
    {
        <option value="@user.ID">@user.Name</option>
    }
</select>

But as the supervisor itself isn't updated, Entity Framework saves the original Supervisor on "Update".
I thought about modifying the setter of SupervisorID in the Prodline class to update the Supervisor, but is that really the only way?
Edit:
my "Put" code:
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

public DbApiClientService(ApiClientOptions apiClientOptions)
{
    _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiClientOptions.ApiBaseAddress);
}

public async Task UpdateItem<T>(T item, int Id)
{
    string endpoint = GetEndpointName<T>();
    var response = await _httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync($"/api/{endpoint}/{Id}", item);

    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

private string GetEndpointName<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).Name;
}


Please show code which actually do Update. Update in EF Core is method for working with detached entities and if you use it probably you are doing something wrong, because EF Core detects changes automatically.

That is the only way.  It is how it is suppose to be done.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I've updated my question, you can see the update code. thanks for your attention!

@jdweng what is?

@jdweng oh I see, I should do setter for xID to set x as null so ef understand it's changed, it's a little weird but ok...

You don't show the EF code that does the actual update. The update code you do show is irrelevant.
